# Does the Radeon drivers that windows 10 auto download/install come with control center?

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon

### If yes to the question above, how do I access it?

A few months ago, this PC was on Windows 10 and I seemed to recall getting access to the Radeon control center by right clicking on the desktop.

I reinstalled windows 10 (was previously on Linux for 3 months) and windows auto downloaded and installed the Radeon drivers but I don't know how to access the control center anymore.

Can you please help? Thanks

Edit: the drivers I got is version 26.20.12028.2 and dated 2019-08-16. I've already restarted the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows will usually only install the necessary drivers themselves; it will not be interested in all the other bells & whistles that the GPU manufacturer has to offer.

If you want all the extra <strike>junk</strike> … ermm…  stuff, you need to go to the manufacturer - in this case [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support)